# TwitterBootstrap JavaScript for specific resolution only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With twitter-bootstrap it is possible to achieve responsive behavior by applying css to markup like `visible-lg` `visible-md` `visible-sm` [responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for example.

But how about if i want to apply specific JavaScript for specific resolution.

lets say I have javascript like that:

```
$('.mainHeader').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 585
        }
    });
```

I want value `top` make dynamic based on current resolution.
lets say if current resolution `visible-lg` I want `top: 20`, if current resolution `visible-md` I want `top: 300` etc..

Is there any clever way to achieve that with twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: Consider using [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

Comment: This might be helpful [window width else if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083508/jquery-window-width-else-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matchMedia` API to detect certain screen width, so you can do this

```
if ( window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches ) {
    $(element).affix({
        offset: {
            top: 585
        }
    });
} else if ( window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches ) {
    // change the affix offset
}
```

Need to know that `matchMedia` API only supported on IE10+ [reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia). The other alternative you can **Modernizr** `mq()` function. Read the [documentation here to learn more](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq).